# create binary graph from weighted data in igraph

Tags: binary, igraph

I have this adjacency matrix

```
> head(adj_mat)

    A2 A11 A6 A7 A10 A12 
A2  18   0  0  0   0   0   
A11 12  13  0  0   0   0   
A6  13  13 15  0   0   0  
A7  11  12 12 12   0   0   
A10  5   6  6  6   6   0   
A12 12  13 13 12   6  13
```

I want to create a binary graph from it, but that only shows edges that has a value > 10

However, if I use the code below, it includes all edges.

```
graph <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_mat, mode="lower", weighted = T, diag = F)
```

Is there a way of doing this in igraph without having to use `ifelse` first and changing the edge values > 10 within the adjacency matrix to binary values?

Comment: `graph <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_mat > 10, mode="lower", weighted = FALSE, diag = FALSE)`

Comment: @GaborCsardi I got this error when using that code: `Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted,  : 
  invalid value supplied for "weighted" argument, please see docs.`

I tried without the `weighted` argument and got the graph I needed. Thank you!